# Range of values for $y$ given $-2 \leq x \leq 3$ and $9 \leq x + y \leq 11$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I want to find the range of values of $y$ for which

> $-2 \leq x \leq 3$ and $9 \leq x + y \leq 11$

Now initially I thought to subtract the inequalities, but that gives $8 \leq y \leq 11$

However, $y$ cannot be any of these values because then $\max x + \max y = 3 + 11 = 14$ and this is bigger than the maximum value of $x + y$.

Any help is appreciated. Probably being a bit stupid!

Comment: Try drawing these curves on a piece of graph paper. It will be insightful. Or you can use online softwares such as desmos too.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$9-x \le y \le 11-x$$

Since $$-3 \le -x \le 2,$$

$$9-3 \le 9-x \le y \le 11-x \le 11+2$$

$$6 \le y \le 13$$

[image]

Comment: But if I do $13 + 3$, e.g. the max y and the max x, I get $16$. But $x +y$ can only be 11 maximum??

Comment: Given the condition $9 \le x+y \le 11$ and $-2 \le x \le 3$, I deduce that $6 \le y \le 13$. When $y=13$, notice that $x$ must be $-2$, it can't take value value $x=3$ simultaneously. Notice that $x$ and $y$ are related in the feasible region. The feasible region is not a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $x=2.5\cos t+0.5$

$$9\le2.5\cos t+0.5+y\le11$$

$$\iff8.5-2.5\cos t\le y\le 10.5-2.5\cos t$$

Now $-\cos t\ge-1\implies y\ge8.5+2.5(-\cos t)\ge8.5-2.5$

Similarly, $-\cos t\le1, y\le10.5+2.5(-\cos t)\le10.5+2.5$

Answer (score 0):

A bit of geometry, consider an $x,y$ coordinate system.

1)$-2 \le x \le3.$

Draw lines parallel to the $y-$axis through $x=-2$ and $x=3.$

2)$9 \le x+y \le 11.$

$x+y=C$ is a line with $y-$intercept $C$ and slope $-1.$

Then $9\le C \le11$,

Draw the lines $y=-x +9$ and $y=-x+11.$

3)The lines in 1) and 2) form a parallelogram, refer to Goh's nice drawing.

4)Allowed $x,y$ values are within this parallelogram.

5)Smallest $y:$

Interception of $y=-x +9$ with $x=3$, i.e. the lower right hand corner of the parallelogram:

$y_{min}=6$.

6)Largest $y:$

Interception of $y=-x+11$ with $x=-2$, i.e. the upper left hand corner of the parallelogram:

$y_{max}=13.$

7)Altogether   $6 \le y\le 13.$